Error self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) expected an indented block after 'if' statement
I want to build face recognition with python, i follow the tutorial at youtube and then this error appear when i try to run the app.
I exactly follow the tutorial right, but i don't know if i miss some of library installation.
So this is the code that i write :
import tkinter as tk
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

import util

class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.main_window = tk.Tk()
        self.main_window.geometry("1000x500+350+100")

        self.login_button_main_window = util.get_button(self.main_window, "Login", "green", self.login)
        self.login_button_main_window.place(x=640, y=300)
        self.register_new_user_button_main_window = util.get_button(self.main_window, "Register New User", "gray", self.register_new_user, fg='black')
        self.register_new_user_button_main_window.place(x=640, y=400)

        self.webcam_label = util.get_img_label(self.main_window)
        self.webcam_label.place(x=10, y=0, width=700, height=500)

        self.add_webcam(self.webcam_label)

    def add_webcam(self, label):
        **if 'cap' not in self.__dict__:
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)**

        self._label = label
        self.process_webcam()

    def process_webcam(self):
        ret, frame = self.cap.read()
        self.most_recent_capture_arr = frame

        img_ =  cv2.cvtColor(self.most_recent_capture_arr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        self.most_recent_capture_pil Image.fromarray(img_)

        imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=self.most_recent_capture_pil)

        self._label.imgtk = imgtk
        self._label.configure(image=imgtk)

        self._label.after(20, self.process_webcam)


    def login(self):
        pass

    def register_new_user(self):
        pass

    def start(self):
        self.main_window.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.start()

And the error is :
 self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block after 'if' statement on line 23

Can someone help me with this problem? because i search for an hour but find nothing.
Fix my face recognition app

Any process you want to be processed on 'if' statement if it's True should be indented.
def add_webcam(self, label):
    if 'cap' not in self.__dict__:
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    self._label = label
    self.process_webcam()

Your code above doesn't have any indented line after 'if' statement, that lead to an error.

But in the video tutorial the code run perfectly fine, there's no problem, and the came is showd just with that code, i have no idea wheres the problem.

Ok i want to verify some stuff, did u indent the code like the tutorial? And maybe the tutorial video link

link you can just backward a few minutes for see the detail of the code

At timestamp 29:39, u can see the indentation on the tutorial code match the example i put above

you just add 1 tab/4 space right before self.cap = .... , because this line is under the scope of  if statement

Im very new with this Py, so what should i do? The code that i put in the thread above is same right? with the video tutorial?

The only different between your code and tutorial (and correction I put on my answer) is Indentation. Just add 1 tab/4 spaces (depending on how you indent your code) before self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) . If necessary, do side by side comparison about your code and mine and take a look very carefully.

Thank you so much, the code now running perfectly fine. But why the cam show up so late? it takes maybe like 5 minutes to showed up.

Happy to help, For performance, I dont really know. Perhaps it took a lot of time to load the library. You can try testing it by measuring the time needed to load the library, opening camera and finally your full program. From that you can optimize part you need to improve.
